# Exclude unused parts of dependencies from jar (Maven)

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-assembly-plugin

We have a small project with some heavy-weight dependencies (e.g. Spring) of which we only use small parts. Therefore, the JAR we get when packing with all dependencies weighs several megabytes, even for out two-class-server. This seems unnecessary.

Is there a way to restrict JAR assembly to actually used (class) files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create a Jar-with-dependencies (your project and the dependencies merged into one big jar) while limiting the classes or packages that are added to that jar. See the [includes / excludes page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) for reference.

If you don't want to manually specify what needs to be included, perhaps there is a way to integrate [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) with your build.

Comment: I found lots of useful references on the ProGuard site, thank you! Even if Maven is not able to do this automatically (shame), there seems to be hope with other tools.

Comment: maven shade plugin now allows automatic filtering via `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` configuration

Comment: I just tried it on a project and it cut my jar size 36%, no additional config needed.

Comment: `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` reduced my JAR's size by more than 50% but at the same time it also "reduced" the JAR's functionality to 0 by throwing out required classes. Guess I'll have to go with manual exclusion of packages... BTW, I am not really disappointed though because, having worked as a developer for close to a decade now, you just anticipate these things ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to include only classes which are used. But you can [exclude dependencies from your depencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to reduce the JAR size. Only drawback: you need to know what you can exclude and what not.