# How to compile Protobuf in a way to get less number of method count

Tags: java, jar, protocol-buffers

We have a project where we use protobufs. When we count the number of methods in generated protobuf .java files they contain around 1000 methods. But when we compile them into a jar and use the method counter ([Is there a way to get count of number methods used in a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023397/is-there-a-way-to-get-count-of-number-methods-used-in-a-jar-file)) it shows up around 40000 methods.

I assume that every sub class which we have contains the same number of methods each super class has. But its just a guess. Is there any way I can compile those in a better way than this?.

This is not a single small project. So changing into other protobuf builders is not a solution. I assume there should be a better way of making jars.

Comment: Why is number of methods a concern for you?

Comment: Android can only have around 65000, methods in whole project. When we add the protobufs it fails

Comment: Are you using Maven? Would any of these do for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957760/exclude-unused-parts-of-dependencies-from-jar-maven http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698814/configure-maven-shade-minimizejar-to-include-class-files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Exclude unused parts of dependencies from jar (Maven)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957760/exclude-unused-parts-of-dependencies-from-jar-maven) and [configure Maven Shade minimizeJar to include class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698814/configure-maven-shade-minimizejar-to-include-class-files). They may well be what you need if you are using Maven to build your software.